# tensorflow library wasn't compiled to use sse4 even though it was

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

When I built my pip package, I followed the instructions to build with the optimizations [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41293077/how-to-compile-tensorflow-with-sse4-2-and-avx-instructions) With the exception, that I don't have a gpu, so I didn't build with cuda. So it looked like this:

```
$ bazel build -c opt --copt=-mavx --copt=-mavx2 --copt=-mfma --copt=-mfpmath=both 
        --copt=-msse4.2 -k //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

I then followed the instructions to update my pip package in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35422388/what-is-bazel-in-tensorflow-when-do-i-need-to-build-again). When I attempted to run my code again, I STILL get the following warnings. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here? Is there a step I missed?

```
2017-07-17 10:35:27.394699: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45]
  The TensorFlow library wasn\'t compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are
      available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-07-17 10:35:27.394722: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] 
  The TensorFlow library wasn\'t compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are 
      available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-07-17 10:35:27.394728: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] 
  The TensorFlow library wasn\'t compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are 
      available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-07-17 10:35:27.394733: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] 
  The TensorFlow library wasn\'t compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are
      available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-07-17 10:35:27.394742: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] 
  The TensorFlow library wasn\'t compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are 
      available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
```

I am also worried that when I run:

```
$ bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/
```

I get the following warnings:

```
Mon Jul 17 10:29:56 MDT 2017 : === Building wheel
warning: no files found matching '*.dll' under directory '*'
warning: no files found matching '*.lib' under directory '*'
warning: no files found matching '*.h' under directory 'tensorflow/include/tensorflow'
warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'tensorflow/include/Eigen'
warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'tensorflow/include/external'
warning: no files found matching '*.h' under directory 'tensorflow/include/google'
warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'tensorflow/include/third_party'
warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'tensorflow/include/unsupported'
~/mlp-va/src/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow
```

**UPDATE:** I ran code while I wasn't in the pip environment (Without running `$ source bin/activate`), and I don't get the errors when I do that.

Comment: Does your update refer to both sets of warnings?

Comment: @iga, yes, it just worked when I wasn't in the pip environment.

Comment: I met same problem. Have you solved this problem?